# FFMPEG spawn promise not resolving

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, es6-promise

I have a problem where running `ffmpeg` with `spawn` using the event listener API for `close` or `exit` events works fine but when I try to convert `spawn` into a `Promise` it does not resolve.

I'm

This works fine

```
 const ls = spawn(ffmpeg_static.path,`-i movie.mov movie.mp4`.split(" ");

    //Listen for processing close
  ls.on("close", (code) => {
        console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
        
     });
```

```
function pspawn(args) {
 
  // *** Return the promise
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
 
    const process = spawn(ffmpeg_static.path, args);
//Listen for close and resolve.
    process.on("close", function (code) {
    
      resolve("Complete");
    });
    process.on("error", function (err) {
       // *** Process creation failed
       reject(err);
    });
  });
}

... 

async function run () {
await pspawn(['-i', 'movie.mov','movie.mp4'])
}
```

I might be missing something simple but can't seem to figure out what it is.

Comment: does it reject? In the first code, you pass a string as the second argument to spawn ... in the second code you pass an array to spawn as the second argument - so the two codes are not the same in the first place

Comment: @JaromandaX, `spawn` method can take as the second parameter either a string or an array of arguments

Comment: @xom9ikk - I must be reading the wrong documentation

Comment: @JaromandaX, sorry i confused `spawn` and `exec`, you are right) for `spawn`, arguments are passed through an array